# Swap part of a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What's the easiest way in Ruby to interchange a part of a string with another value. Let's say that I have an email, and I want to check it on two domains, but I don't know which one I'll get as an input. The app I'm building should work with @gmail.com and @googlemail.com domains.

Example:

```
swap_string 'user@gmail.com' # >>user@googlemail.com
swap_string 'user@googlemail.com' # >>user@gmail.com
```

Comment: I can see that the comments involve using an if statement and two .sub calls. I think that's pretty obvious, but I assumed you can do it smarter with Ruby.

Comment: Smart code is good. Obvious code is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `googlemail.com` and `gmail.com` are the only two possibilities, you can use [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) to replace a pattern with given replacement:

```
def swap_string(str)
   if str =~ /gmail.com$/
     str.sub("gmail.com","googlemail.com")
   else
     str.sub("googlemail.com","gmail.com")
   end
end

swap_string 'user@gmail.com'
# => "user@googlemail.com"

swap_string 'user@googlemail.com'
# => "user@gmail.com"
```

Comment: destructive operations? Bad choice.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to substitute a part of a string with something else, gsub works quite well.

[Link to Gsub docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub)

It lets you match a part of a string with regex, and then substitute just that part with another string. Naturally, in place of regex, you can just use a specific string.

Example:

```
"user@gmail.com".gsub(/@gmail/, '@googlemail')
```

is equal to

```
user@googlemail.com
```

In my example I used @gmail and @googlemail instead of just gmail and googlemail. The reason for this is to make sure it's not an account with gmail in the name. It's unlikely, but could happen.

Don't match the .com either, as that can change depending on where the user's email is.

Comment: Why `gsub` rather than `sub`? Your "EDIT" makes sense (to guard against "my_gmail@gmail.com`), so why not just change your answer to incorporate that?

Comment: `gsub` or `sub` makes no difference in this case. Personally I tend to reach for `gsub` since that behaves as I'd expect a substitution to. That's just habit / personal preference, either works. I've now incorporated the EDIT into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Ruby gsub :

eg:

```
  "user@gmail.com".gsub("gmail.com","googlemail.com");
```

As per your need of passing a string parameter in a function this should do:

```
def swap_mails(str)

if str =~ /gmail.com$/

   str.sub('gmail.com','googlemail.com');

else

   str.sub('googlemail.com','gmail.com');

end 

end


swap_mails "vgmail@gmail.com" //vgmail@googlemail.com

swap_mails "vgmail@googlemail.com" ////vgmail@gmail.com
```

Comment: `"bugmail@gmail.com".gsub("gmail","googlemail") #=> "bugooglemail@googlemail"`. The lecture on `gsub` is out-of-place. Keep your answers short and too-the-point.

Answer (score 0):

`String` has a neat trick up it's sleeve in the form of [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
def swap_string(string, lookups = {})
  string.tap do |s|
    lookups.each { |find, replace| s[find] = replace and break if s[find] }
  end
end

# Example Usage

lookups = {"googlemail.com"=>"gmail.com", "gmail.com"=>"googlemail.com"}

swap_string("user@gmail.com", lookups) # => user@googlemail.com
swap_string("user@googlemail.com", lookups) # => user@gmail.com
```

Allowing `lookups` to be passed to your method makes it more reusable but you could just as easily have that hash inside of the method itself.

Comment: Sorry, I was going off of memory. I updated to include `if s[find]` to avoid an `IndexError` in the case that the range in the string isn't found.

Comment: In the block to lookups, aren't you replacing `googlemail.com` with `gmail.com`, and then again replacing `gmail.com` (next lookup) with `googlemail.com` ?

Comment: @limekin yes I was. I just updated to include `and break` in the case that a `find/replace` is found.

Answer (score 0):

My addition :

```
def swap_domain str
  str[/.+@/] + [ 'gmail.com', 'googlemail.com' ].detect do |d|
    d != str.split('@')[1]
  end
end

swap_domain 'user@gmail.com' 
#=> user@googlemail.com
swap_domain 'user@googlemail.com' 
#=> user@gmail.com
```

And this is bad code, imo.